# Docusign Listener Argument Null (dev Sandbox)

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a webmethod in a C# webservice that listens for Docusign to call when an Envelope status changes:

```
[WebMethod]

        public void DocuSignConnectUpdate(DocuSignEnvelopeInformation DocuSignEnvelopeInformation)
        {
            
            //Check if null
            if (DocuSignEnvelopeInformation == null)
            {
                File.WriteAllText("C:\\websites\\DataAPI\\datalog.txt", "Data: " + "Data is null");
            }
            else
            {
                string envelopeId = "";
                try
                {
                    //Write a line in a file
                    File.WriteAllText("C:\\websites\\DataAPI\\datalog.txt", "Data: " + DocuSignEnvelopeInformation.ToString());
     
                    //Get some data out
                    envelopeId = DocuSignEnvelopeInformation.EnvelopeStatus.EnvelopeID;

                    //Write Data to a file
                    File.WriteAllText("C:\\websites\\DataAPI\\innerdatalog.txt", "Data: " + DocuSignEnvelopeInformation.ToString());


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // could not serialize
                    File.WriteAllText("C:\\websites\\DataAPI\\errorlog.txt", "Exception: " + ex.Message);
                    
                    throw new SoapException(ex.Message, SoapException.ClientFaultCode);
                }

                
            }
```

The issue I am having is that DocuSignEnvelopeInformation argument is not being set when called, so the code keeps terminating at the if==null statement.  When I run the envelope data to the API using SoapUI everything works correctly.  Any ideas what I'm missing would be appreciated.

EDIT:  I wanted to Add the Interface here too since I forgot it originally

```
    [ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "IOperations", Namespace = "https://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
    public interface IOperations
    {
        
        [OperationContract(Action = "DocuSignConnectListener/Operations/DocuSignConnectUpdate")]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        string DocuSignConnectUpdate(DocuSignEnvelopeInformation DocuSignEnvelopeInformation);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured this out, turns out it just wasn't pretty enough so I added a decoration specifically:

```
[SoapDocumentMethod("http://tempuri.org/DocuSignConnectUpdate",
            RequestNamespace = "http://tempuri.org",
            ResponseNamespace = "http://tempuri.org",
            Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,
            ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
```

on the method and now everything works like its supposed too.  Now that I look at it, it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

When a DocuSign webhook is set to use `SOAP` mode, the notification is sent as a SOAP request to your server (your listener).

If SOAP mode is off, then the notification is sent as a regular POST request with an XML body.

In your question, you say that

> When I run the envelope data to the API using SoapUI everything works correctly

So it sounds like everything is worked as designed.

Comment: I agree it seems like everything working right, but the method argument isn't set when the call comes from Docusign, only when I send send it via SoapUI, and I have no idea why.

Comment: In SOAP mode, the request is to a SOAP service **DocuSignConnectUpdate**. The following may also help: [MS link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f75d3314-5e62-411a-a8d8-c20e5a02f726/docusign-connect-serialization?forum=wcf)

Comment: I edited by original post to include the interface since I forgot that originally.  I thought this may have been the issue too, and I have tried every combination I can think of.  I've even completely rebuilt this as a stand alone wcf and can't get it to work I just keep getting the same errors. I have a feeling its unable to serialize the input from Docusign but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any further ideas. An alternative configuration is to use a platform as a service system as an intermediate queuing system. This enables you to receive the notifications from behind your firewall with no changes to your firewall. See [blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4)

Comment: Thanks Larry, I may have to try that route, I'm not sure what I have wrong I'm grabbing the actual stream and the SOAP being fed into the service looks fine, it just acts like it isn't setting the DocuSignEnvelopeInformation argument variable.